# LaTeX, image isn't showing up where I expect it to?

Tags: latex

I am very new to LaTeX, and using it to write a term paper for university. Everything wrt to text is going okay. I'm trying to insert an image into the file, but whenever I do it either shows at the top of the section, at the top of the following page or on a new page, depending on which directives I use.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
 ***skip***
\section{Timeline}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

"a paragraph goes here" 

\begin{figure}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{chronology.png}
\caption{Chronology of initial attack on NHS systems (NHS 2017)}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\section{Motivation}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
```

This is the section for the image I'm trying to insert. I want it to be right under the `Timeline` section (see images below), however it is showing up in the middle of the following section on a new page.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correct it to have the desired outcome?

I am using TeXmaker if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre], including a class and the necessary package, which allows us to reproduce your problem. Without knowing your class, this is just a guess: floating specifier like `\begin{figure}[htbp]` might help

Comment: i added in the preamble, sorry!

Comment: Your code fragment does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a package called "float" in combination with the [H] option for your figure:

```
\usepackage{float}

...
    
\section{Timeline}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

"a paragraph goes here" 

\begin{figure}[H]
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{chronology.png}
\caption{Chronology of initial attack on NHS systems (NHS 2017)}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\section{Motivation}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
```

Refer to this post [force-figure-placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text) for clarification

Comment: No problem! Had the same problem just yesterday.

Comment: @CPace Using the `H` option usually gives poor results and can add excitative white spaces to your document. You should try to use `[htbp]` instead to allow latex to find a good place for your figure